# AWS S3 File Upload Issue - MalformedXML Error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files to an S3 bucket using the AWS SDK, and I've set up the necessary AWS credentials and parameters. However, I keep getting a `Error uploading files: MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema` error, and I'm not sure what's causing it. I've double-checked the XML data and the credentials, but the issue persists.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully upload files to S3.

```
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

...


    const fileUploadHandler = (files) => {
        setLoading(true);
        console.time('upload');

        const uploadPromises = Array.from(files).map((file) => {

            const params = {
                Bucket: 'chasescroll-videos',
                Key: file.name,
                Body: file,
                ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
            };

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const upload = new Upload({
                    client: new S3Client({
                        region: 'eu-west-2',
                        credentials: cred,
                    },),
                    leavePartsOnError: false,
                    params: params,
                });

                upload.done()
                    .then(
                        (data) => resolve(data),
                        (error) => reject(error)
                    );
            });
        });

        Promise.all(uploadPromises)
            .then((results) => {
                let urls = results.map((r) => ({ file: r.key, url: r.location }));
                setUploadedFile([...urls, ...uploadedFile]);
                setLoading(false);
                console.timeEnd('upload');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    };
```

Screenshot of Network Tab

it shows call with `x-id=UploadPart` get success but `x-id=CompleteMultipartUpload` throw error

[image: Network tab]

Comment: yes i tried with multiple files but the issue was from the ETag config, when i made configuration to expose ETag header, it start working

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by configuring the ETag header correctly. made changes in cors to expose the ETag header in the configuration. This change enabled successful file uploads.